# Disable menu key

Tags: keyboard

I want to disable "menu" key that emulates right click. It is unfortunately placed on my keyboard and I keep hitting it by mistake instead of AltGr.

This is the key I am talking about.

[image: The key]

Is it possible to just permanently disable it? Either make it working as AltGr, or just disable it outright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to system settings --> keyboard --> Shortcuts and locate the menu key in the list. Click on it and hit backspace to disable it.

*Note, this answer didn't workfor me that's why I wrote the other one. But this answer works for @KarelBílek, then it will work for others.*

Answer (score 2):

the keycode for my menu button is 135. Try for yourself so you disable the correct key.

To test what keycode it is type `xev` in terminal. Then hit the key and nothing else and look for the keycode in the text in the terminal.

Now execute this command in a new terminal window.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 135 = NoSymbol'
```

This disables the key and solves your problem. :)

[resource](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842970&s=9f1a09a3e7f6e7cded7fa83c1194c33f&p=5276944#post5276944)

Comment: Well, that was simple! Thanks! Will accept answer as soon as it's possible.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Interesting. The first idea worked actually in my case, so you could add it back. Or, as a separate answer.

Comment: Just in case if you were wondering how to go the other way around, i.e. map  right click action to menu key: change NoSymbol to Menu ;)